# AD B2C Keep me signed in - maximum session length?

Tags: session, azure-ad-b2c

What is the maximal length for a KMSI Session in AD B2C? Is it possible to make it never expire?

Functionality is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-kmsi-custom

But I didn't find documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is the maximum value of an Int32, 2,147,483,648 seconds = 68 years.

Comment: Do you know if this is documented by Microsoft somewhere? Or how do you know this information?

Comment: It is not documented, I am part of the Product Team.

Answer (score 0):

If you set SessionExpiryType = Rolling. then as per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57288836/9922), you only need to log in once every 68 years!